# scroll bar not visible in Iphone and safari browser

Tags: html, css

I made a div that has a scroll function. The scroll bars appear on my desktop browsers (chrome, firefox) but when it comes to mobile, the scrollbar isn't visible.

How can I make this visible all the time?

```
.scroll_text {
    max-height: 250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 220px;
    height: 100%;
}
.scroll_text::-webkit-scrollbar {  
    width: 8px;
    -webkit-width:8px;  
    -webkit-appearance: none;  
}  
.scroll_text::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 8px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.scroll_text::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  
    background-color: #DDE2E5;
}  
.scroll_text::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {  
   background-color: #c99d5e;
   border: 1px solid rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.5);
   border-radius: 10px;
}  
.scroll_text::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {  
    background-color: #000;  
    
}  
.scroll_text:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {  
    background-color: #c99d5e;
    border: 1px solid rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an OS-specific setting. I'm not sure where it is on iPhone but on MacOS:
[image]